# How could I set gradient fixed background on UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, gradient

I used following code.

```
CAGradientLayer* collectionRadient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
collectionRadient.bounds = self.collectionView.bounds;
collectionRadient.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
collectionRadient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor],(id)[endColor CGColor], nil];
[self.collectionView.layer insertSublayer:collectionRadient atIndex:0];
```

But it drawn on cells included images. so cell was not shown.

I want to draw gradient background of UICollectionView under Cells and fixed it when view scrolled.
Let me know Please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this... You have to assign a view to use background view.

```
CAGradientLayer* collectionGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
collectionGradient.bounds = self.view.bounds;
collectionGradient.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
collectionGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
UIView *vv = [[UIView alloc] init];
vview.backgroundView = vv;
[vview.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:collectionGradient atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Can you explain what is your vview?

Answer (score 4):

**Directions**

1. Create a view
2. Assign that view to the backgroundView of you collectionView
3. Create a gradient
4. Add gradient layer to collectionView backgroundView

**Code Swift 4.2**

```
  private func addBackgroundGradient() {
    let collectionViewBackgroundView = UIView()
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame.size = view.frame.size
    // Start and end for left to right gradient
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    collectionView.backgroundView = collectionViewBackgroundView
    collectionView.backgroundView?.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
  }
```

If you want a top to bottom gradient all you have to do is remove [endPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer/1462412-endpoint) and [startPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer/1462408-startpoint). You can read more about gradients [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer).

Note that startPoint and endPoint are defined in the coordinate plane from `(0.0, 0.0)` to `(1.0, 1.0)`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3.0**

I like to start with a custom class for gradients

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {
    //set your start color
    @IBInspectable var startColor:   UIColor = UIColor.black { didSet { updateColors() }}
    //set your end color
    @IBInspectable var endColor:     UIColor = UIColor.white { didSet { updateColors() }}
    //you can change anchors and directions
    @IBInspectable var startLocation: Double =   0.05 { didSet { updateLocations() }}
    @IBInspectable var endLocation:   Double =   0.95 { didSet { updateLocations() }}
    @IBInspectable var horizontalMode:  Bool =  false { didSet { updatePoints() }}
    @IBInspectable var diagonalMode:    Bool =  false { didSet { updatePoints() }}
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }
    func updatePoints() {
        if horizontalMode {
            gradientLayer.startPoint = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0) : CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        } else {
            gradientLayer.startPoint = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) : CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        }
    }
    func updateLocations() {
        gradientLayer.locations = [startLocation as NSNumber, endLocation as NSNumber]
    }
    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors    = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePoints()
        updateLocations()
        updateColors()
    }
}
```

With the custom class somewhere in the project and added to the target you just need to do as mentioned earlier and add it as a background view rather than background color or separate normal view sent to the back

Implement like so:

```
let gradient = GradientView()
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
//add to your collectionView
collectionView?.addSubview(gradient)
collectionView?.sendSubview(toBack: gradient)
self.collectionView?.backgroundView = gradient
```